# How to bring frosty-glass effect for div over another div that contain texts

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a `frosty-glass` effect on a div`.` There are few examples over internet on how to achieve this, however most of them say that, you have a background image for your `body` then you have a small `div` over it and want to have `frosty-glass` effect for that small `div`.

However my case is slightly different as I dont have any background image rather some text (or any other `DOM` for that matter) under a `div`, there is another `div` which covers that 1st `div` partially and I want to have `frosty-glass` effect on that 2nd `div`. Below is a little example

**HTML**

```
<div class = 'parent'>
  <div class = 'top'>

  </div>
  <div class = 'bottom'>
    Some div...
  </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.parent {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}

.top {
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
.bottom {
  height: 150;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

I am looking for to have the `frosty-glass` effect for `div` with class `top` which is actually `fixed positioned`.

The `Codepen` example - https://codepen.io/Volabos/pen/RwWxwQd

Is there any way to have that effect using CSS?

Thanks for any pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the css `filter` property, eg. `filter: blur(3px);`.

Find a demo based on yours [here](https://codepen.io/sircodewright/pen/bGVaNwg).